# Current and voltage word problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

If a conductor with a current of 200mA passing through it converts 40 J of electrical energy into heat in 30 seconds, what is the potential drop across the current ?

The answer is 6KV, but I don't know what methods to use to get this answer.

Comment: $P = I \times V$.

Comment: but this doesn't give me 6kv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $I = 200$mA, $E = 40$J, $t = 30$s, and you want to find the voltage drop.

First, you should know that $P = V \cdot I$, so $V = \frac{P}{I}$

Second, you have the amount of energy converted in a certain amount of time, so $E = P \cdot t$

So, find the power and use it to find the voltage drop.

Comment: this works , but i thought energy was defined by W = P * t whitch would then be P = W/t

Comment: You're right, that was my mistake. Sorry about that :)

Answer (score 1):

> The answer is 6KV

Let's check that:

$$6\mathrm{kV} \cdot 0.2 \mathrm{A} \cdot 30 \mathrm{s} = 36\mathrm{kJ}$$

But this result is 3 orders of magnitude larger than $40\mathrm{J}$ so I would carefully check the given numbers and units.

Comment: Yeah, i'm starting to think the answer at the back of my book is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the voltage you should remember that this problem involves dissipated power. Therefore you should use P = VI as this is the easiest variation.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
1.Heat generated in time $T$ is equal to $I^2R T$
2.potential drop is equal to $IR$